# Windows phone store access for multiple users

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Is there any possibility to add another accounts to manage published application for Windows Phone?

I was looking something similar to this:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it is currently not possible.